# Passing Jekyll variables "up" scope

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to set a Jekyll (Liquid) variable in my content page, and exposing that variable and its content in the including Jekyll template.  In this use case, I want to author the main page content, and side-bar content in a single MD file, but control the injection of said content.

Here is my setup..

**_layouts/default.html**

```
<div>{{ content }}</div>
<div class="side-bar">{% include sidebar.html sidebarContent=sidebar %}
```

**_includes/sidebar.html**

```
{{ include.sidebarContent }}
```

**pages/my-content-page.md**

```
----
layout:default
----

This is the main content portion's content.

{% capture sidebar %}
This is the sidebar content

* one
* two
{% endcapture %}
```

It seems like there is no way to pass the "sidebar" variable UP the scope; I can only seem to pass it down. All i want to to do is separate the content authoring for a single page (which consists of 2 discrete areas; Content and Sidebar) and avoid introducing layout marking into my "content" files (aka the MD files).

If there is a way i can break them out into different MD files i'db be open to that as well... ex.

```
my-page.md
my_page_sidebar.md
```

or

```
my_page/index.md
my_page/sidebar.md
```

I have some leeway in this as im building out using pages not posts.

Answer (score 4):

From a page, you can get datas from `front matter` and `content` itself when you are in a layout. So only `page.something` variables are available.

But, there is no way to `capture` or `assign` in page content and get the resulting variable from a layout.

You can try to store your sidebar in your front matter, but it can be tricky.

One solution can be to separate content from sidebar with something like an [excerpt separator](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#default-configuration) used by posts.

In `_config.yml`, set

```
content_separator: "<!--separator-->"
```

In your page :

```
This is the main content portion's content.

{{ site.content_separator }}

This is the sidebar content

* one
* two
```

In your template :

```
{% assign contentSplitted = content | split: site.content_separator %}
{% assign myContent = contentSplitted | first %}
{% assign navbar = contentSplitted | last %}

<div>{{ myContent }}</div>
<div class="side-bar">{{ navbar }}</div>
```

Note I use `myContent` as `content` variable is already in use.

Comment: Wow! I loved this idea @DavidJacquel! Very inspiring! :)

Comment: Cool. But I think you can separate content from navigation in an other way. Why, exactly, are you mixing content and navigation ? Is it an in page navigation ?